# Prove that $G=\langle a,b\; | \; abab^2=1\rangle$ is infinite cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Prove that $G=\langle a,b\; | \; abab^2=1\rangle$ is infinite cyclic.

First I proved that $a=(ab)^3$ and also $b=(ab)^{-2}$.
By using these, I proved that $G$ is abelian and $G=\langle ab\rangle$.
However, since the order of $a$ and $b$ is not given, I have no idea on proving the order of $ab$ is infinite.

Comment: It need not be infinite. Take $a = [3], b = [2] \in \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$. Then $abab^2 = [0]$ but $G = \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ is not infinite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The homomorphism $G \to \mathbb{Z}$ given by $a \to 3, b \to -2$ is well-defined and surjective.

Comment: By using your idea,I define $\phi:G\rightarrow \Bbb{Z}$ by $\phi(a^xb^y)=3x-2y$. In particular, $\phi(ab)=1$. So it is surjective homomorphism with kernel $\langle a^2b^3 \rangle$. So $\langle ab \rangle / \langle a^2 b^3 \rangle \cong \Bbb{Z}$. Is this sufficient to say that $G$ is infinite cyclic?

Comment: @AlanWang: You've shown its cyclic, and it must be infinite since it has a surjection to the infinite set $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Just one thing to make sure, if $G$ is cyclic and $G/H\cong \Bbb{Z}$ there is no way for $G$ to be finite right?

Comment: Sure: $\#G \geq \#G/H = \#\mathbb{Z}$. The argument here that $G$ is infinite doesn't use that fact that it's cyclic.

Answer (score 3):

Once you've proved $G$ is abelian, you can re-interpret the presentation in terms of abelian groups. First, $G$ is isomorphic to the quotient of $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} = \langle a \rangle \oplus \langle b \rangle$ modulo the subgroup $\langle 2a+3b \rangle$.

Since $2a+3b$ is a primitive element of $\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}$, there is an automorphism of $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ taking $2a+3b$ to $a$. With little trouble you can write down a $2 \times 2$ integer matrix of determinant $1$ that represents this autoomorphism.

So $G$ is isomorphic to $\langle a\rangle \oplus \langle b\rangle $ modulo $\langle a \rangle $ which is evidently infinite cyclic.